# python extract word from multiple lines into 1 list

Tags: python, list, split, strip

I am trying to extract unique words out of the following text into 1 list.

```
But soft what light through yonder window breaks
It is the east and Juliet is the sun
Arise fair sun and kill the envious moon
Who is already sick and pale with grief
```

But I keep getting a list within the list for each line of the text. I understand I have some "\n" to get rid of but can't figure out how.

Here is my code:

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
lst = list()
for line in fh:
    line = line.rstrip("\n")
    for word in line:
        word = line.lower().split()
        lst.append(word)
print(lst)
```

And the output I get:

```
[['but', 'soft', 'what', 'light', 'through', 'yonder', 'window', 'breaks'], ['it', 'is', 'the', 'east', 'and', 'juliet', 'is', 'the', 'sun'], ['arise', 'fair', 'sun', 'and', 'kill', 'the', 'envious', 'moon'], ['who', 'is', 'already', 'sick', 'and', 'pale', 'with', 'grief']]
```

Thanks!!

Comment: `for word in line: word =line.lower().split()` .There is no use for `word in line` here, since you're reassigning `word` directly below it. Instead: `for word in line.split(): lst.append(word)` may be closer to what you want.

Comment: Thanks all for your help, those were very helpful. And much cleaner than the solution I came up with: using a `count = count + 1` loop with `word[count]`.

Answer (score 3):

When you do `line.lower.split()` you get a List of words. You're appending a list of words to your list, lst. Use extend instead of append. Extend would add each element of the list returned by the split() function. Also the second for loop `for word in line:` is unnecessary. 
Additionally, if you want to extract unique words, you might want to look into the set datatype.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
list += word
```

Instead of:

```
lst.append(word)
```

Comment: **Append** add list to list, but **+** combines them.

Comment: `.extend` would likely be more explicit.  Also works with non-list iterables.

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension does the same like you've done.

Then use [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to *chain* all the sublists into one list:

```
from itertools import chain

lst = list(chain.from_iterable(line.lower().split() for line in f))
```

Comment: The OP doesn't want a nested list, they are trying to get the result of strings only, not sublists of strings.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I had misread OP's question. Thanks for that

Comment: please use [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) instead of `chain(*[..])`.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Thanks for the eye

Answer (score 0):

If the order is not important, you can use set instead of list:

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
uniq_words = set()
for line in fh:
    line = line.strip()
    uniq_words_in_line = line.split(' ')
    uniq_words.update(uniq_words_in_line)
print(uniq_words)
```

Comment: you may want to use `.update` to do in-place union instead of recreating a new set every step.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen, good suggestion, I just updated my answer.

Comment: Update takes any iterable, no need for a set call.

Answer (score 0):

As @Shalan and @BladeMight suggested, the issue is that `word = line.lower().split()` produces a list, and `append` appends the list rather than adding to it. I think a syntactically simple way to write this would be:

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
lst = list()
for line in fh:
    line = line.rstrip("\n")
lst += line.lower().split()
```